# Accessing Docker containers by their domain name

Tags: networking, docker

hey guys I have a docker container A with a domain name attached to it on a host B with a domain name attached to it as well.....how can I access the said container A via A's domain name rather than an B's ip address or domain name from computer C on the host B's local network.

thus C -> A( via wwww.cname.url) rather than C -> B( www.bname.url:port) -> A

Answer (score 3):

You should create an A record in the DNS for `www.cname.url` pointing to the IP address on host *B*. On *B* you should create a NAT that maps ports 80 and 443 to the docker instance (*A*).

To provide a better answer, you should provide more details. How is your docker instance setup, how many and which IP addresses are being used on host *B*, how has networking been setup in docker, etc etc.